# Create from-to pairs from a pandas `dataframe`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a input dataframe as :

```
import pandas as pd
df_input = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' : ['id_1', 'id_1', 'id_1', 'id_2', 'id_2', 'id_2', 'id_3', 'id_4', 'id_4'],
    'stage' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'D'],
    'date' : pd.to_datetime(['2020-01-01', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-15', 
                '2020-01-02', '2020-01-07', '2020-01-21', 
                '2020-01-05', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-05'])
})
```

[image]

From the above dataframe, I want to create `from-to` pairs. The `id` & `date` column will be used to determine the `from` & `to`, if a `stage` the last pair will be `stage_name-None`.
Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note: Try not to name a variable as a builtin eg: input is a builtin*- I have considered the dataframe as `inp`

You can use shift after `sort_values` and `assign` the column to stage after renaming it and using it as a dataframe:

```
a = inp.sort_values(['id','date'])
out = a['stage'].to_frame('from').assign(to=a.groupby("id")['stage'].shift(-1))
```

---

```
print(out)

  from   to
0    A    B
1    B    C
2    C  NaN
3    B    C
4    C    D
5    D  NaN
6    B  NaN
7    A    D
8    D  NaN
```

Comment: Got it, thanks @anky. The `to` and `from` column names are swapped, but I get the idea.